# LaTeX: Is there any way to get a warning if a package is loaded twice?

Tags: package, latex, warnings

it would be nice if LaTeX could tell me that a package is loaded more then once, for example:

```
\usepackage{anypackage}
\usepackage{anypackage}
```

Is there any way to get this behavior?

Comment: Apparently no. But [unless you use `\RequirePackage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58244/loading-package-twice-with-requirepackage-causes-option-clash), it seems to be [not a big problem itself](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79110/loading-a-package-more-than-once) :)